# google admin SDK for non admin-user

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

1. I created google app in developer console.
2. Enable Admin SDK
3. Enable API access
4. In "Manage OAuth Client access" i added  "Authorized API client" with
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" scope.

Further, i want to get users from my domain.

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

ArrayList<String> scopeList = new ArrayList<>();
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY);
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setTransport(httpTransport)
          .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
          .setServiceAccountId("bla-bla@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
          .setServiceAccountScopes(scopeList)
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("p12 file")))
          .setServiceAccountUser("superadmin@my-domain.com")
          .build();

credential.setAccessToken("access token of current google user");

Directory admin = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
          .setApplicationName("Capsidea")
          .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
return admin.users().list().setDomain("my-domain.com").execute();
```

All it's working when i login into google via OAuth by superadmin@my-domain.com.
But when i logined by some-user-non-admin@my-domain.com i have the error:
**"Not Authorized to access this resource/api"**

Can an non admin user to get a list of all users in the domain?
When the domain change this code will work given that it is necessary to specify superadmin'a ?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

setServiceAccountUser needs a user capable of Admin API usage (there is a fine-grained role configuration tool).

Do state that such a user is needed for your code to work.