# Non-admin read-only access to Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

In [a post on the Google Developers blog](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/09/new-features-in-admin-sdk-custom-user_23.html) from September 23, 2014, it says:

> **Read access to all domain users**
>
> Historically, only admins have been able to access the data in the Admin SDK.
>   Beginning today, any user (not just admins) will now be able to call the
>   Directory API to read the profile of any user on the domain (of course, we
>   will respect ACLing settings and profile sharing settings).

However, despite checking every Google Apps Admin setting I can find, my calls calls to the Directory API fail for non-admin users. Condensed code:

```
params = {
  client_id: XXXXXX, 
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly', 
  response_type: 'token id_token', 
  immediate: true
};
gapi.auth.authorize(params, gHandleAuthResult);
var request = gapi.client.request({
  'path': '/admin/directory/v1/users',
  'params': {
     'customer': 'my_customer',
  }
});
request.then(function (response) {
  var users = response.result.users;
  if (!!users && users.length > 0) {
    users.forEach(function (user) {
      newMember.id = user.id || '';
    }
  }
}
```

This is using the Google API Client Library for JavaScript. I've tried this on multiple Google Apps accounts, it always works for admin accounts, never for non-admins, for whom I get the response "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

A [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359557/google-admin-sdk-for-non-admin-user) asked about this and received a response that you have to use a service account, but that was from June 2014, before the blog post. I have succeeded in making the call using a service account, but would rather not have to do so as it requires a server to act as a bridge.

The Google developer docs say that "Google engineers monitor and answer against the tag google-admin-sdk", so hoping for an answer from Google here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
  'path': '/admin/directory/v1/users',
  'viewType': 'domain_public'
  'params': {
  'customer': 'my_customer',
  }
});
```

viewType=domain_public is needed to perform Directory operations as a non-admin as [described in the reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list). There's also a bit more explanation in [the user accounts docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#retrieve_users_non_admin).

Comment: Thanks! Missed that in the docs. In the spirit of this feature, since users can view the Groups Directory (respecting the Admin setting `Information->Directory->List this Group`), as well as members (respecting `Permissions->Access Permissions->View Members`), it's too bad domain users can't use `/admin/directory/v1/groups` and `/admin/directory/v1/groups/{id}/members` to access this same data via API. Unless I missed that somewhere too?

Comment: Currently non-admins are only allowed to call users.list() and users.get().