# How can I impersonate an admin user from Google API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-javascript-client

I am trying to make a request for `gapi.client.directory.users.list` with the following parameters:

```
'customer': 'my_customer',
'maxResults': 100,
'orderBy': 'email'
```

getting a success result when my account is an admin of the domain. When I do the same request using a **non-admin** account, it return a 403 result.

I went to https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients and added the *_______.apps.googleusercontent.com* as client and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly as scope. Even this way I got a 403 result.

I saw some 'impersonating' functions in Java and Python... but nothing for Javascript in a browser context, not NodeJS.

Can someone help me to allow the request to list users in admin directory api for common users of my domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some browsing, the parameter **viewType** is *required* to allow non-admin users to fetch directory data.

```
gapi.client.directory.users.list({
    'viewType': 'domain_public',
    'customer': 'my_customer',
    'maxResults': 100,
    'orderBy': 'email'
}
```

I found it in the docs: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#domain_public after @jay-lee answer: [Non-admin read-only access to Google Admin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267606/non-admin-read-only-access-to-google-admin-sdk/30270839#30270839)